# how to get license key from c#

Tags: c#, registry

I am trying to create my own license system for my applications. Therefore, I am trying to read registry key but I couldnt do it succesfully.

I have created a registry key manually and the code below doesnt read it.

here is the regedit screen

[image]

here is my code below

```
// The Registry key we'll check

// *********** it returns null**********************
RegistryKey licenseKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Acme\\HostKeys");

if ( licenseKey != null )  
{
    // Passed the first test, which is the existence of the
    // Registry key itself. Now obtain the stored value
    // associated with our app's GUID.
    string strLic = (string)licenseKey.GetValue("test"); // reflected!
    if ( strLic != null ) 
    {
        // Passed the second test, which is some value
        // exists that's associated with our app's GUID.
        if ( String.Compare("Installed",strLic,false) == 0 )
        {
            // Got it...valid license...
            return new RuntimeRegistryLicense(type);
        } // if
    } // if
} // if
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is your app x86 (32 bit and your OS 64 bit?

Also, a license key in the registyr is very, VERY hack prone.

Comment: my app and OS 64bit.

Comment: What does your licenseKey.GetValue("test") return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to open the `test` key first and then read null.

```
RegistryKey licenseKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\\Acme\\HostKeys\\test");

if ( licenseKey != null )  
{
    string strLic = (string)licenseKey.GetValue(null); // GetValue(null) will return the default of the key.
    if ( strLic != null ) 
    {
        if ( String.Compare("Installed",strLic,false) == 0 )
        {
            return new RuntimeRegistryLicense(type);
        } 
    } 
}
```

What you were trying to do was read a value called `test` under the `HostKeys` Key.